# best ways to Decode and process Binary Bytes from files

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing, binaryfiles

I am trying to decode and process Binary data file, following is a data format
`input:9,data:443,gps:3`
and has more data in the same fashion, `[key:value]` format.

basically, I need to create a dictionary of the file to process it later.

input:`b'input:9,data:443,gps:3'`

Desired output:`{'input': '9', 'data': '443', 'gps': '3'}`

Comment: please provide desired output

Comment: id doesn't look like binary bytes data but normal text data and you can use normal string functions to split it - `split(',')` and `split(':')`

Comment: Where did you get the information that the data format is in the form `input:9,data:443,gps:3`? The original description might be more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input data is [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes)(sequence of bytes). To convert it to `str` object you can use [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode). Than you can work with data lie with sting and split it by `,` and `:`. Code:

```
inp = b"input:9,data:443,gps:3"
out = dict(s.split(":") for s in inp.decode().split(","))
```

Comment: m getting this error :
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 337: invalid start byte @Olivn

Comment: @ZombieCoder8, 0xb5 is not valid utf-8 charcode. You can provide correct encoding as argument of `decode()` function

Comment: some of the file is following format
\x8a\x03C#\xdbVcFZp\xb7\t\xc1\x95>=p6\xd8\xc8\xf3C\x1c\x0bv\x81\x0bn\xbd\xd6\x92_k\xf2\xd8D\xb8P6\x93a\xf5\xa8J\x9d\xbf4\xc9p\\\xd1\xa7\x9a\xbc\x1e\x85\xe9\xea\xd6X\xfe\xd46owZ+\xbcg\xb5\xd0\r#\xbb\xab4U\xe7\xd6\x11\x10W\xf6\x0bl\xb7\xd4\xfeM\x990\xfe\x85\xac\x1c:\x0b\xb3\x9dS%o\t@\xe1\xb6\x7f\xe0\x10G\xe0c\xd7,\xf1\x87\xf9\x8d\xef@\x9d\x92\xf6\x1c\xd5Z\xeb\x860Nk

Comment: @ZombieCoder8, is it text? or encoded text? or waht is this? It's not obvious from data you've posted.

Comment: sorry I am new to programming, the file is encoded.

Comment: @ZombieCoder8, I don't know, you should work on it. Or ask another question with more details.

Comment: Well, since the OP accepted the answer, I assumed the solution worked. @Zombie, Un-accept the answer since it is based on an inaccurate interpretation of your question.

Comment: @alexis, my answer based on provided input and output. Or I should answer few times every time question will be changed?

Comment: @Olvin you can ask that on meta. But in this case the question was always about *binary bytes*, and you guessed (reasonably but incorrectly, it turned out) that it was not actually a binary file. So don't blame the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The string `input:9,data:443,gps:3` is text, not binary data, so I am going to *guess* that it is a format template, not a sample of the file contents. This format would mean that your file has an "input" field that is 9 bytes long, followed by 443 bytes of "data", followed by a 3-byte "gps" value. This description does not specify the types of the fields, so it is incomplete; but it's a start.

The Python tool for structured binary files is the module [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html). Here's how to extract the three fields as `bytes` objects:

```
import struct

with open("some_file.bin", "rb") as binfile:
    content = binfile.read()
    input_, data, gps = struct.unpack("9s443s3s", content)
```

The function `struct.unpack` provides many other formats besides `s`; this is just an example. But there is no specifier for plain text strings, so if `input_` is a text string, the next step is to convert it:

```
    input_ = input_.decode("ascii")   # or other encoding
```

Since you ask for a dictionary of the results, here is one way:

```
result = { "input":input_, "data": data, "gps": gps }
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution using `eval`:

```py
inp = b"input:9,data:443,gps:3"
out = eval(b'dict(%s)' % inp.replace(b':', b'='))
```

Comment: You should _never_ reach for a "solution using `eval`"... and especially not when a simple, clean solution exists.

Comment: What is so bad with an `eval` solution?

Comment: @dtrckd, [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).